# magento multi store share cart issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, multistore

**I am building a magento site with 1 website and 2 stores and 1 store view for each store.**

Each store will sell different products.
When customers buy a product from store A, and go to store B buy another product, then they checkout, we want the cart to show the product from store A and store B.

Is it possible with magento without hacking/overriding the core files?

Answer (score 1):

Without hacking core files, yes...without rewriting core files, I don't think so.
This is not a built in feature of Magento.
I was able to implement what you are asking for here, almost 2 years ago.
I'm not sure that it works on newer magento versions but you can give it a try:
http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2013/01/share-cart-between-websites.html.
The idea is to modify the method that stores and retrieves the cart id from the session (`Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::_getQuoteIdKey`), and the method that verifies the store views that can share the cart (`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getSharedStoreIds`).
Full code and explanations are provided in the link posted above.
It's kind of long to replicate it in here.

Comment: im not sharing the cart between website but stores instead, the stores are still on the same website.

Comment: For 2 store views under the same website it should work out of the box...I think.

Comment: yes it works but there is one issue. when viewing the cart, all files has the same base url. when viewing the cart from domain.com/storeA/ all products have same domain.com/storeA/ including the products that came from storeB.